# PHPUnit can't find a class loaded in the bootstrap

Tags: php, phpunit

My problem with PHPUnit is quite simple: if the test class file is included in the bootstrap file, PHPUnit won't be able to find the test class.
You can easily recreate the issue:

The file hierarchy:

- ./tests/MyTest.php
- ./bootstrap.php
- ./phpunit.xml

phpunit.xml

```xml
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="MyTest">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

bootstrap.php:

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ .'/tests/MyTest.php';
```

tests/MyTest.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testTrue()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

In this case, when I run `./vendor/bin/phpunit`, it returns *"No tests executed!"*. And if I run `./vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests/MyTest.php`, it returns *"Class 'MyTest' could not be found in '[...]\tests\MyTest.php'."*.

Now, if I remove the second require_once from autoload.php, both commands work as expected.

I've only seen a couple of similar issues on stack. They are six years old and have not been resolved, which makes me think that not allowing this way of loading classes is actually a design choice.

Could you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `require` insteand of using `composer.json` to handle the autoloading? Are you using a framework at all or plain PHP?

Comment: Yes, I am using a framework that has a class discovery feature (e.g. automatically scanning all classes that have a specific interface), which involve requiring all php files in the project. The tests directories are also scanned when the env=test. I can fix this, but PHPUnit not being able to get an already-loaded class got me curious.